# OnClickListener in listview item always takes the last row

Tags: android

I download data from server and fill the listview with them. Every item in the listview has 3 buttons, on every button I would like to make an onclicklistener. When the user clicks one of the buttons, It should for example open the new activity. Every row (object) has some id, and when I click on some of these buttons, the id is always for example 15 (it is always the id of the last row in listview). 
I have tried to declare the OnClickListeners with many different ways, the result was the same.

LawsAdapter

```
public class LawsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Law> implements View.OnClickListener {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

private UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
private IsVotedStorage isVotedStorage;
private View convertView;
private ViewHolder viewHolder;

/**
 * Constructor, declares storages, context and inflater
 * @param context
 * @param textViewResourceId
 */
public LawsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.context = context;
    inflater =  ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(context);
    isVotedStorage = new IsVotedStorage(context);
}

/**
 * Second constructor, here you can set the resource (againstr the previous one)
 * @param context
 * @param resource
 * @param items
 */
public LawsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Law> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(context);
    isVotedStorage = new IsVotedStorage(context);
}

/**
 * Overriden method getView, declares graphic objects (btns... ) and set listeners
 * @param position
 * @param convertView
 * @param parent
 * @return view
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.law_item, parent, false);
        this.convertView = convertView;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemName);
        viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemDescription);
        viewHolder.tvStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemStatus);

        viewHolder.btnDownvote = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemDownvote);
        viewHolder.btnUpvote = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemUpvote);
        viewHolder.btnMakeComment = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemMakeComment);
        viewHolder.currentLaw = getItem(position);
        Log.d("View holder", "new one");
        Log.d("LAW ID, ADAPTER", String.valueOf(viewHolder.currentLaw.getId()));

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getName());
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getDescription());

        viewHolder.tvStatus.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getStateValue());

        setSurfacesColors();

        viewHolder.btnMakeComment.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.btnDownvote.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.btnUpvote.setOnClickListener(this);

        disableIfVoted();

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Log.d("View holder", "get tag");
    }

    return convertView;
}


/**
 * Set the colors of surfaces
 */
private void setSurfacesColors() {
    viewHolder.sfLeft = (SurfaceView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemSurfaceLeft);
    viewHolder.sfBackground = (SurfaceView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemSurfaceBackground);
    Log.d("VOTES", "Positive: " +  viewHolder.currentLaw.getPositiveVotes() + " Negative: " + viewHolder.currentLaw.getNegativeVotes());
    if ((viewHolder.currentLaw.getNegativePercent() + viewHolder.currentLaw.getNegativeVotes()) > 1) {
        viewHolder.sfBackground.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.redSurfaceBckg));
        viewHolder.sfLeft.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.btnSubmitColor));

        int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
        int upvote = viewHolder.currentLaw.getNegativePercent();
        int downvote = viewHolder.currentLaw.getPositivePercent();
        int positivePixels = (screenWidth / 100) * upvote;
        int negativePixels = (screenWidth / 100) * downvote;

        viewHolder.sfBackground.getHolder().setFixedSize(negativePixels, 5);
        viewHolder.sfLeft.getHolder().setFixedSize(positivePixels, 5);
        Log.d("UPDATE", "NOTIFY");
    }
    else {
        viewHolder.sfBackground.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.greySurface));
        viewHolder.sfLeft.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.greySurface));
    }
}

/**
 * Upvote
 * @param law
 */
private void upvote(Law law) {
    ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(context);
    serverRequest.upvoteLawInBackground(law.getId(), new UpDownCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(Law law) {
            viewHolder.currentLaw = law;
            setSurfacesColors();
            Log.e("VOTES in UPVOTE", "Positive: " + viewHolder.currentLaw.getPositiveVotes() + " Negative: " + viewHolder.currentLaw.getNegativeVotes());
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Downvote
 * @param law
 */
private void downvote(Law law) {
    ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(context);
    serverRequest.downvoteLawInBackground(law.getId(), new UpDownCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(Law law) {
            viewHolder.currentLaw = law;
            setSurfacesColors();
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Get screen width in pixels
 * @return int screen width
 */
private int getScreenWidth() {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    return width;
}

/**
 * Disable voting button if I have already voted
 */
private void disableIfVoted() {
    if (isVotedStorage.isVoted(viewHolder.currentLaw.getId())) {
        viewHolder.btnUpvote.setEnabled(false);
        viewHolder.btnDownvote.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.lawItemMakeComment:
            if (userLocalStore.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                Log.d("ON CLICK LAW ID", String.valueOf(viewHolder.currentLaw.getId()));
                Intent commentsIntent = new Intent(context, DialogCommentsActivity.class);
                commentsIntent.putExtra("law_id", viewHolder.currentLaw.getId());
                commentsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                Log.d("CURRENT LAW", viewHolder.currentLaw.getId() + " " + viewHolder.currentLaw.getName());
                context.startActivity(commentsIntent);
            } else {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DialogSignInActivity.class));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.lawItemDownvote:
            if (userLocalStore.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                isVotedStorage.setVoted(true, viewHolder.currentLaw.getId());
                downvote(viewHolder.currentLaw);
                disableIfVoted();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DialogSignInActivity.class));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.lawItemUpvote:
            if (userLocalStore.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                isVotedStorage.setVoted(true, viewHolder.currentLaw.getId());
                upvote(viewHolder.currentLaw);
                disableIfVoted();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DialogSignInActivity.class));
            }
            break;
    }
 }

/**
 * Holds items per row
 */
private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvName;
    private TextView tvDescription;
    private TextView tvStatus;
    private Button btnUpvote;
    private Button btnDownvote;
    private Button btnMakeComment;
    private SurfaceView sfBackground;
    private SurfaceView sfLeft;
    private Law currentLaw;
}
```

}

law_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="6pt"
    android:background="@color/button_material_light">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/background_floating_material_light"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:id="@+id/rel">


        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lawItemSurfaceBackground"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lawItemSurfaceLeft"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lawItemSurfaceBackground"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lawItemSurfaceBackground"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lawItemName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lawItemSurfaceBackground"
            android:layout_marginTop="2pt"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3pt"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:padding="1pt"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lawItemName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:padding="1pt"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3pt"
            android:id="@+id/lawItemDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="1pt"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3pt"
            android:id="@+id/lawItemStatus"
            android:layout_marginRight="30pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lawItemDescription"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/lawItemStatus"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/btnSubmitColor"
                android:textColor="@color/btnSubmitTextColor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="@string/button_upvote"
                android:id="@+id/lawItemUpvote" />

            <Button android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/btnSubmitColor"
                android:textColor="@color/btnSubmitTextColor"
                android:text="@string/button_downvote"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:id="@+id/lawItemDownvote" />

            <Button android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/btnSubmitColor"
                android:textColor="@color/btnSubmitTextColor"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="@string/button_comment"
                android:id="@+id/lawItemMakeComment" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Example: I click on the btnMakeComment in first row, the new Activity opens and download from db comments of the object with id 15. Then I click on the btnMakeComment in the third row and the new Activity opens and download from db comments of the object with the same id, like last time (again 15). 
But in the ListView are not the same rows/objects, they are differentm just on click it seems like they would be the same.

DialogCommentsActivity

```
    /**
 * Activity for adding and reading comments
 */
public class DialogCommentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener, AbsListView.OnScrollListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private int lawId;
    private int limit;
    private int offset;

    private int preLast;
    private int page;

    private ListView listView;
    private EditText etAddComment;
    private List<Comment> activityCommentList;
    private UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    private User user;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    private CommentsAdapter commentsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments_dialog);
        setTitle("");
        setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.commentDialogListView);
        limit = 5;
        offset = 0;
        page = 1;
        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
        user = userLocalStore.getLoggedUser();

        etAddComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentDialogEditAdd);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.commentsDialogSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setEnabled(false);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String userName;
        dumpIntent(getIntent());
        if (extras != null) {
            lawId = extras.getInt("law_id");
        }
        Log.e("LAW ID HOHOHO", String.valueOf(lawId));
        fillAdapter(limit, offset);

        etAddComment.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                    btnSubmit.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    btnSubmit.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail_law, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        switch(listView.getId()) {
            case R.id.commentDialogListView:
                Log.d("SCROLL", "scroll");
                boolean loadMore =  firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount-1;
                if (loadMore) {
                    page += 1;
 //                   offset = (page * limit) - limit + 1;
 //                   fillAdapter(limit, offset);
//                    commentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); TODO
                }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }

    public void fillAdapter(int limit, int offset) {
        ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(this);
        Log.e("LAWID BEFORE REQUEST", String.valueOf(lawId));
        serverRequest.fetchCommentsInBackground(lawId, limit, offset, new GetCommentsCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Comment> comments) {
                commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.comment_item, comments);
                listView.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);
                activityCommentList = commentsAdapter.getList();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadData(int limit, int offset) {
        ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(this);
        Log.e("LAWID BEFORE REQUEST", String.valueOf(lawId));
        serverRequest.fetchCommentsInBackground(lawId, limit, offset, new GetCommentsCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Comment> comments) {
                // Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                for (Comment comment : comments) {
                    Log.d("COMMENT OBJECT", comment.getText());
                    activityCommentList.add(comment);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Handle click events, comments adding
     * @param v
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.commentsDialogSubmit:
                String text = String.valueOf(etAddComment.getText());
                Date dt = new Date();
                Log.d("Click", "Click");

                if (userLocalStore.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                    Log.e("LAW ID NEW COMM", String.valueOf(lawId));
                    Comment comment = new Comment(text, dt, user, lawId);
                    addComment(comment);
                    etAddComment.setText("");

                    //notifyData(limit, offset);
                    limit = 15;
                    offset = 0;
                    fillAdapter(limit, offset);
                    commentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.e("NUMBER OF COMMENTS", String.valueOf(activityCommentList.size()));
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Insert comment
     * @param comment
     */
    public void addComment(Comment comment) {
        ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(this);
        serverRequest.storeCommentInBackground(comment, new GetCommentsCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Comment> list) {
                Log.d("Comment", "Comment was added.");
            }
        });
    }


    private void dumpIntent(Intent i) {
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
            Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
            Log.e("EXTRAS", "Dumping Intent start");
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                Log.e("EXTRAS", "[" + key + "=" + bundle.get(key) + "]");
            }
            Log.e("EXTRAS", "Dumping Intent end");
        }
    }

}
```

SOLUTION:

I added ViewHolder viewHolder = v.getTag(); in every listener (and before it setTag(viewHolder) in getView on every button

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.law_item, parent, false);
            this.convertView = convertView;
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.position = position;
            viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemName);
            viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemDescription);
            viewHolder.tvStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemStatus);

            viewHolder.btnDownvote = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemDownvote);
            viewHolder.btnUpvote = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemUpvote);
            viewHolder.btnMakeComment = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemMakeComment);

            viewHolder.btnMakeComment.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.btnDownvote.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.btnUpvote.setTag(viewHolder);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            Log.d("View holder", "get tag");
        }

        viewHolder.currentLaw = getItem(position);
        Log.d("View holder", "new one");
        Log.d("LAW ID, ADAPTER", String.valueOf(viewHolder.currentLaw.getId()));

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getName());
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getDescription());

        viewHolder.tvStatus.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getStateValue());

        setSurfacesColors();

        disableIfVoted();

        viewHolder.btnMakeComment.setOnClickListener(onCommentClickListener);
        viewHolder.btnDownvote.setOnClickListener(onDowvnvoteClickListener);
        viewHolder.btnUpvote.setOnClickListener(onUpvoteClickListener);


     //   viewHolder.btnMakeComment.setOnClickListener(onCommentClickListener);




        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return laws.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Law getItem(int position) {
        return laws.get(position);
    }



    /**
     * On upvote listener
     */
    private View.OnClickListener onUpvoteClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            if (userLocalStore.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                isVotedStorage.setVoted(true, viewHolder.currentLaw.getId());
                upvote(viewHolder.currentLaw);
                disableIfVoted();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DialogSignInActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * On downvote listener
     */
    private View.OnClickListener onDowvnvoteClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            if (userLocalStore.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                isVotedStorage.setVoted(true, viewHolder.currentLaw.getId());
                downvote(viewHolder.currentLaw);
                disableIfVoted();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DialogSignInActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * On comment listener, open comment dialog
     */
    private View.OnClickListener onCommentClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            if (userLocalStore.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                Log.d("ON CLICK LAW ID", String.valueOf(viewHolder.currentLaw.getId()));
                Intent commentsIntent = new Intent(context, DialogCommentsActivity.class);
                commentsIntent.putExtra("law_id", viewHolder.currentLaw.getId());
                commentsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                Log.d("CURRENT LAW", viewHolder.currentLaw.getId() + " " + viewHolder.currentLaw.getName());
                context.startActivity(commentsIntent);
            } else {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DialogSignInActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: There is no function in onItemClick() that handles click event on ListView. Also in your Adapter Class I can't see where you override getItemId(int position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting last id/ last row position every time because  last view reders at last

To get row position on button click you can set postion as tags to your buttons and check that tags in `onclickListner`

For example in your `getview()` method put position as tag in `viewHolder.btnMakeComment` button

`viewHolder.btnMakeComment.setTag(position);` and in `OnClickListner` Check tag
`int position = (int)v.getTag();`

Comment: Could you give me some example of code please? I have tried this, but it ends with the nullpointexception. 

In getView

`viewHolder.btnMakeComment.setTag(position);`

`viewHolder.btnMakeComment = (Button) viewHolder.btnMakeComment.getTag(position);
        viewHolder.btnMakeComment.setOnClickListener(onCommentClickListener);`

Answer (score 0):

Change your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.law_item, parent, false);
        this.convertView = convertView;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemName);
        viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemDescription);
        viewHolder.tvStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemStatus);

        viewHolder.btnDownvote = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemDownvote);
        viewHolder.btnUpvote = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemUpvote);
        viewHolder.btnMakeComment = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lawItemMakeComment);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Log.d("View holder", "get tag");
    }


    viewHolder.currentLaw = getItem(position);
        Log.d("View holder", "new one");
        Log.d("LAW ID, ADAPTER", String.valueOf(viewHolder.currentLaw.getId()));

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getName());
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getDescription());

        viewHolder.tvStatus.setText(viewHolder.currentLaw.getStateValue());

        setSurfacesColors();

                viewHolder.btnMakeComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //position -> get id
                    //action
                }
            })
            viewHolder.btnDownvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //position -> get id
                    //action
                }
            });
            viewHolder.btnUpvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //position -> get id
                    //action
                }
            });

        disableIfVoted();

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this bt i am not sure:

```
    ArrayList<String> Ex=new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i<youriDvalue.length; i++)

        {      
            Ex.add(currentVerse_speak.get(i)); 

            //(or)
            String []ex1;     
            ex1=currentVerse_speak.get(i)+"~";   
            exi[i]=currentVerse_speak.get(i).toString();

         }

    txtview.settext(Ex.toString());   
    txtview.settext(ex1.tosting());
```