# setVisibility adjusts wrong button in custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-custom-view, android-button

I have a custom listview with text and play-pause buttons. I'm trying to make play button invisible when play button clicked. But when i do that in onClick, button at wrong position is disappearing on listview. Like; buttons : A - B - C - D - E, when i click C, then E become invisible. I have no idea how to handle, please help.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private String[] gelenurl;
List<String> gelen_ad;
MediaPlayer mPlayer= new MediaPlayer();

private int[] IMAGE_ID = {R.drawable.police};
private int layout;
public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects, String[] arr) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    layout=resource;
    gelenurl=arr;
    gelen_ad=objects;
}


ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
@NonNull
@Override

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder mainViewholder = null;
    convertView=null;

    if(convertView==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView=inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);
        viewHolder.img.setImageResource(IMAGE_ID[0]);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
        viewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
        viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
        viewHolder.stop_button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_stop_btn);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    else {

        mainViewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        mainViewholder.title.setText(getItem(position));

    }

    viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                viewHolder.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                radioLinks(gelenurl[position]);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public void radioLinks(String city) throws IOException {

            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.reset();


            }

            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(city);
            mPlayer.prepareAsync();


            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    mPlayer.start();

                }
            });

        }

    });

    viewHolder.stop_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.reset();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewHolder` is a class member variable. (`ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder()`), so each time you enter `getView()` and `convertView` is `null`, you set up the same `viewHolder`. As a result, whatever values were most recently set in `getView()` is what is operated upon in `onClick()`. You probably want to create a new view holder when `convertView` is null rather then use the same member variable.

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview). Look at `getView()` in the class `PersonsAdapter`. There is a new view holder created every time a new view is created. You will want to set your `onClickListener` to the button in this newly created viewholder.

Here is your reworked `getView()`. It's untested, but should give you the right idea. Good luck!

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mainViewholder;

//        convertView = null; you don't need this if you reuse the view properly
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            mainViewholder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(mainViewholder);
        } else {
            // If you are reusing a view, you may need to reset values in its view holder.
            mainViewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // You always need to set you viewholder member variables whether creating a new
        // view or converting an old view.
        mainViewholder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);
        mainViewholder.img.setImageResource(IMAGE_ID[0]);
        mainViewholder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
        mainViewholder.title.setText(getItem(position));
        mainViewholder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
        mainViewholder.stop_button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_stop_btn);

        final ViewHolder vh = mainViewholder; // final to use in the click listener
        mainViewholder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    vh.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    radioLinks(gelenurl[position]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, i am new on Android, I have not enough knowledge to apply your recommendations on my code. please can you explain with sample code what should i do?

Comment: @PinkRabbits I'll look for a good example online and post it here. That should be helpful.

Comment: @PinkRabbits Since the button you have the click listener set to is the button you want to make invisible you could just code `v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` in the click listener since `v` will be the button. You can then dispense with `vh`.

Comment: I understood working principle thanks to you. it worked, thank you so much for helping me, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting last id or last row position every time because last view renders at last

To get row position on button click you can set postion as tags to your buttons and check that tags in onclickListner

For example in your

```
getview()
```

method put position as tags in your viewholder.btn

```
viewHolder.btn.setTag(position);
```

and in OnClickListner

Check tag

```
int position = (int)v.getTag();
```

for reference [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32285078/6761707)

Comment: i did not consider from this point of view, thank you so much for help